# I can't generate the SH1. when I run ./gradlew signingReport

Tags: java, flutter, firebase, gradlew

- What went wrong:
  An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']

> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
> Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
> Your current JDK is located in C:\Program Files\Eclipse Foundation\jdk-8.0.302.8-hotspot\jre
> You can try some of the following options:
> - changing the IDE settings.
> - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
> - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.

I did write the ./gradlew signingReport inside the Android folder but it did not work. it shows an error.

Comment: Have you tried to change the version of the JDK to 11? Besides that, "did not work" it's hard to help with. What exactly didn't work?

Comment: I already fixed it. I put the way i used to fix it down. thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps to fix it for Windows:

check your jave version. Open CMD and run:

```
java -version
```

look for jdk version, it should be 11 and above. if not open this website [Java 17 version](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk17-archive-downloads.html) and download the **Windows x64 Installer** of **Java SE Development Kit 17.0.10.**

after that install it, now you need to open the **Environment Variables** > **system Variables**.

click: **New**. for the variable name : **JAVA_HOME**
Variable value: **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17** please make sure the variable value is correct, look for it in the C drive to make sure it's there.

after that open the **Path** in the **System Variables** and click new write: `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`

Save everything. close you compiler and cmd. make sure when you run java -version, it shows the version we download. now you can run ./gradlew signingReport.

Comment: Nice to see that you have added the solution as an answer ;)